# Error running Django's test suite

Tags: python, django

I've been working in some tickets of Django project. I'm currently working in a ticket for the `1.7` branch. When I try to execute the whole test suite I get this error:

```
$user ~/workspace/Code/django/tests $ PYTHONPATH=..:$PYTHONPATH ./runtests.py
Testing against Django installed in '/home/user/workspace/Code/django/django'
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./runtests.py", line 410, in <module>
    options.failfast, args)
  File "./runtests.py", line 252, in django_tests
    test_labels or get_installed(), extra_tests=extra_tests)
  File "/home/user/workspace/Code/django/django/test/runner.py", line 147, in run_tests
    old_config = self.setup_databases()
  File "/home/user/workspace/Code/django/django/test/runner.py", line 109, in setup_databases
    return setup_databases(self.verbosity, self.interactive, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/workspace/Code/django/django/test/runner.py", line 299, in setup_databases
    serialize=connection.settings_dict.get("TEST", {}).get("SERIALIZE", True),
  File "/home/user/workspace/Code/django/django/db/backends/creation.py", line 385, in create_test_db
    self.connection._test_serialized_contents = self.serialize_db_to_string()
  File "/home/user/workspace/Code/django/django/db/backends/creation.py", line 421, in serialize_db_to_string
    serializers.serialize("json", get_objects(), indent=None, stream=out)
  File "/home/user/workspace/Code/django/django/core/serializers/__init__.py", line 128, in serialize
    s.serialize(queryset, **options)
  File "/home/user/workspace/Code/django/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 52, in serialize
    for obj in queryset:
  File "/home/user/workspace/Code/django/django/db/backends/creation.py", line 417, in get_objects
    for obj in queryset.iterator():
  File "/home/user/workspace/Code/django/django/db/models/query.py", line 265, in iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "/home/user/workspace/Code/django/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 700, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
  File "/home/user/workspace/Code/django/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 786, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/user/workspace/Code/django/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/user/workspace/Code/django/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/user/workspace/Code/django/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/user/workspace/Code/django/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 485, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: sites_framework_syndicatedarticle
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it doing: `git clean -fdx`.

I hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your setting file

```
if 'test' in sys.argv:
    DATABASES = {
        'default':{
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': ':memory:',
            'TEST_NAME': ':memory:',
        },
    }
```